# initiate a call by clicking button on ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i was using a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555 " Call me" to call , but it is not initiating the call directly rather than putting the number in the box / asking for confirmation ..can i call directly , as if we click "Call Me" and the call gets started, i am using ionic + angular do i have to include cordova , have checked this articale but not much help:

http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

Comment: you can't start the call using the: `<a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555" class="button button-positive">Call me</a>`

Comment: no, ios it falls into a box first saying , "call or cancel" and in android phones it goes to the dialer screen with number , then i have to click and call ...want to remove this step, want a call directly , we click call me and the call gets initiated.

Comment: Exactly as I said.. you can't do it using the `tel:` you will need here a native  code intervention.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put this in your `config.xml` file for the `href tel:phonenumber` to work

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555 " will not work as you want, add this [plugin](https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin) to your project by running command 
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin.git`

and in your project use this line to make call

```
window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, number);
```

`onSuccess` and `onError` are callback functions, so declare them also.
 
**Note**: If you have skype installed, it will ask you to either make call from skype or direct phone. Otherwise it will directly start call.

**Full JS Code:**

```
 $scope.CallNumber = function(){ 
    var number = '18002005555' ; 
    window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(function(){
     //success logic goes here
    }, function(){
     //error logic goes here
    }, number) 
  };
```

Comment: Like this :  <ion-item menu-close  ng-click="CallNumber()">
        Call me
        </ion-item>
 And in the js file    $scope.CallNumber = function(){
var number = '18002005555' ; 
window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, number).onSuccess(function(){

alert("Success");

}).onError(function(){
alert("Error");
});
};

Comment: hi mudasser can you please provide me a running jsfiddle for that , i have tried it is saying Module 'Callnumber' is not available , i am a bit new to angular. i am adding this to                                                       angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers' , 'Callnumber'])  and in controller .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout , CallNumber )

Comment: This will only work on real device. Callnumber will only be available on real device.