# cordova/ionic CallNumberPlugin does not work on phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make call on phone using cordova/ionic.I am using CallNumberPlugin but it is not working.When i tried first time then it worked but now it is not working.It does not go to the dialer screen with number.I have tried this `<a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555" class="button button-positive">Call me</a>`  but no use.CallNumberPlugin is in plugin folder of the project and i am calling CallNumber.js from index page.It is Neither giving any error neither working.Can some one please help me to resolve this problem?

```
<ion-view class="dashboard">
    <ion-content class="top-109">

         <a href="tel: 110">call</a>

     </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Which platform you are targeting for?

Comment: I am using angular js

Comment: I am asking for which platform the app will run? Is it for Android or iOS or both.

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413505/initiate-a-call-by-clicking-button-on-ionic-app

Comment: @Shweta Could you post your HTML code?

Comment: @Avijit I am doing it for Android

Comment: @Shweta Have you included cordova.js and registered deviceready event? In case of Ionic, are you invoking plugin code inside platform ready function?

Comment: @Gandhi I am new for ionic and cordova .can you please elaborate what does mean by invoking plugin code inside platform ready function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer with the following code.

index.html

```
<ul class="list" ng-controller="PhoneCtrl">
        <li class="item">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item">Item 3</li>
        <li class="item"><button ng-click="placeCall(07875509715)">Call</button></li>
      </ul>
```

app.js

```
.controller('PhoneCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.placeCall = function(num) {
        console.log('Place Call ' + num);
        if (window.cordova) {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open('tel:' + num, '_system');
        }
    }
});
```

Download the InAppBrowser plugin.

Answer (score 2):

its simple to access calling in ionic app.

```
 <a class="item item-icon-left " ng-href="tel:91xxxxxxxx" >call:91xxx</a>
```

the above code is fine but we want to add access permission in config file

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

write the code in **config.xml** file

Answer (score 0):

I used OnsenUi with cordova and it worked fine for me. I will share my code with you.

**Html**

```
<ons-button modifier="large--cta" style="width:100%; background-color:lightgreen" ng-click="callNumber()">Call</ons-button>
```

**Js**

```
var supportPhone = "+10000000001";
$scope.callNumber = function () {
    window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(function () {},
    function (e) {
        alert('error:' + e)
    },
    supportPhone);
};
```

If anyone needs some help leave a comment.

Happy Coding.
-Charitha-

Comment: should i replace ons-button as ion-button for ionic?

Comment: I guess yes.... I used OnsenUI so its ons- thats why. just try a normal html button. It should work

Comment: I am getting an alert class not found.

Comment: did you use a normal button ? or Just copied the code ?

Comment: I used ionic buttons

Comment: Can you please tell me y is this showing an error and how can i fix it?what classes i need to add?

Comment: can you upload an image? and may be your html code and js